# How to limit file type within C/C++/Java when uploading with file_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I hope that only C/C++/Java files can be uploaded.

Is it possible to add limitations with `:accept` option like

`<%= f.file_field, :file, accept:'xxx/xxx' %>`

Comment: See my answer and mark it as answer if it works for your needs. :)

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and give you feedback ASAP.

Comment: It's really good, but I'm asked to use ajax instead. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Please update your question to what exactly you want..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can add a server side validation in the Model that checks the format of the file:

```
   validates :file, allow_blank: true, format: {
     with: %r{\.(java|c|cpp)\Z}i,
     message: 'file must be in JAVA, C, CPP format'
   }
```